# Error : Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to insert data in a database table from two other tables

Whenever I run my code, it would return this particular error

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll - Additional information: Fatal error encountered during command execution.

which is pointed at

```
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Have you run that SQL directly in SQL Workbench to confirm it is valid?

Comment: @mjwills i ran in HeidiSql but dosn't work for me it takes munch time to excute !

Comment: If it didn't work in SQL Workbench, why are you expecting it to work from C#?

Comment: @mjwills sometimes it works for me and the data are inserted correctly in the database but the exception always appear that's my problem and yes i did cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue; always same error

Comment: Always try to specify LEFT JOIN or INNER JOIN in a query. What's the workbench error ?

Comment: Have you tried setting a longer `CommandTimeout`?

Comment: @DanielE.  it takes munch time to excute and there is no error in HeidiSql so how i will update my query with left or inner ?

Comment: @mjwills yes cmd.CommandTimeout = int.MaxValue;

Comment: Does the exception appear immediately or after some time?  Sure its "exercices" & not "exercises" ?

Comment: @AlexK. yes exercices french language and the exception appear after some time

Comment: Try ' EXPLAIN SELECT e1.annee,e1.AA,e2.region
            FROM bilan e1 JOIN data e2
            ON e1.siren = e2.siren ' And edit your question with the result

Comment: @DanielE.  i did it and i edited my question with the result  !

Comment: Please paste all the exception details (with all inner exceptions) as text; instructions here: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger i added that into my question

Comment: @mecab95 It simply sounds like your query is timing out during execution. You could try setting `cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400;` or you could try creating indexes that might speed up the `JOIN`: `CREATE INDEX bilan_siren ON bilan(siren); CREATE INDEX data_siren ON data(siren);`

Comment: also try closing your connection properly in the C# code. Put `conn.Close();` after the executeNonQuery command.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger  when i added cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400; it takes munch time to excute and i'am still waiting !! and for creating indexes where i will add them exactly ?

Comment: @ADyson i have conn.Close(); also i added that

Comment: @BradleyGrainger it is working but it takes munch time to excute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's working now !!

It simply sounds like your query is timing out during execution. You could try setting cmd.CommandTimeout = 86400; or you could try creating indexes that might speed up the JOIN: CREATE INDEX bilan_siren ON bilan(siren); CREATE INDEX data_siren ON data(siren);

Answer by Bradley Grainger

Answer (score 1):

I solved that issue by using a old version of MySQL Net.
In my case, I installed the version **6.4.4**. 
But you can download others versions at:

https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/c-net/